# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^2 x^{2k+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^2 x^{2k+1}$, $|x| < 1$. So far I have simplified this to $$x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^2 x^{2k}.$$ I know I most likely need to use some trick to rewrite the series in terms of the derivative of $x$, but I'm not sure how to do that in this specific case.

Comment: it is $$-\frac{x^3 \left(x^2+1\right)}{\left(x^2-1\right)^3}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I know the answer, but I need to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by considering the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2w^k.
$$
Note that we can write $k^2=k(k-1)+k$, so that
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2w^k&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k-1)w^k+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kw^k\\
&=\underbrace{0}_{k=1}+w^2\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k(k-1)w^{k-2}+w\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kw^{k-1}\\
&=w^2\frac{d^2}{dw^2}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}w^k\right]+w\frac{d}{dw}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}w^k\right]\\
&=w^2\frac{d^2}{dw^2}\left[\frac{1}{1-w}\right]+w\frac{d}{dw}\left[\frac{1}{1-w}\right]\\
&=\frac{2w^2}{(1-w)^3}+\frac{w}{(1-w)^2}.
\end{align*}
$$
This all holds as long as $\lvert w\rvert<1$.  Now, by plugging in $w=x^2$, we find that
$$
x\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2x^{2k}=\frac{2x^5}{(1-x^2)^3}+\frac{x^3}{(1-x^2)^2}.
$$
as long as $\lvert x^2\rvert<1$ (which of course holds iff $\lvert x\rvert<1$).